# SOQL With Owner Fields cause Errors

Tags: apex, soql, user, owner

I'm trying to receive some fields from Owner in a custom object.

Some of the standard fields are retrieving perfectly and some throws me an error.

Example:

```
[SELECT Name, Fields__c,Field2__C Owner.Name, Owner.Phone, Owner.MobilePhone, Owner.Email FROM CustomObject__c];
```

All fields are retrieving except Owner.mobilePhone - and I got the next Error:

> ```
> No such column 'MobilePhone' on entity 'Name'.
> ```

Which mobile phone is a standard field in the User object.

I saw this post : 
https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/salesforce/A/question/47467.html

But it 5+ years ago.. something changed?

I prefer not creating a new field as a formula to fix it and use this custom Field in the SOQL query.

Any other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: does your user have access to that field

Comment: Hi,
Beucase it the User object I dont have the Field-Level Security For the standard fields - only for the custom fields.. If you have another way where can I check it I would like to hear.
Thanks

Comment: As owner is a polymorphic as also mentioned by muchavie, another option is to add `WHERE Owner.Type = 'User'` to filter, that would only get records where owner is a user and not a queue.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that User.Owner is a polymorphic field.  That is it can reference either a User object or a Group object.   Personally, I just do another query on User via the OwnerId field once I've checked that this Id a User object not a group.   I'm interested in finding out if there's a better way of handling this.

Why does Owner.Phone work in this situation and Owner.MobilePhone not work when Group has not Phone field?   I have no clue.

Answer (score 2):

As the `Owner` field can be a polymorphic field, you can only access those fields which are common across both objects.

In such cases, you can use [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) in your SOQL query and select the fields based on the Owner type.

```
SELECT 
    [fieldList,] 
    [TYPEOF typeOfField 
        {WHEN whenObjectType THEN whenFieldList}[...] 
        [ELSE elseFieldList] 
    END][...] 
FROM objectType
```

So you can write your query like below

```
SELECT TYPEOF Owner 
    WHEN User THEN UserFields 
    WHEN Group THEN GroupFields END
FROM CASE
```

Your final query will be something like below wherin you can select the fields based on the type and this will return you `List<CustomObject__c>`

```
SELECT Id, Name, Fields__c,Field2__c, 
    TYPEOF Owner 
        WHEN User THEN Name, Email, Phone, MobilePhone 
        WHEN Group THEN Name, Email 
    END
FROM CustomObject__c
```